# cakephp Js helper

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, helper

I want to do something like this.

If I click on some `DIV (id='#some-link')`, it should show me the another `DIV (id='#busy-indicator')`.

I have written following, but it's not working.

```
$this->Js->get('#some-link')->event('click', $this->Js->get('#busy-indicator')->effect('fadeIn'));
```

What should be the correction to get it working?

It generates following output.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#busy-indicator").bind("click", function (event) {
      $("#busy-indicator").fadeIn();
      return false;
   });
});
```

Comment: Are you including jQuery? It's not automatically included by CakePHP.  Also, check that you are writing the JavaScript cache using `$this->Js->writeBuffer();` at the bottom of your view/layout.

Comment: yes, I have included jQuery and $this->Js->writeBuffer(); is already there at bottom of layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a "two-step" solution like this:

```
$event = $this->Js->get('#busy-indicator')->effect('fadeIn');

$this->Js->get('#some-link')->event('click', $event);
```

This is the HTML output:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  $("#some-link").bind("click", function(event) {
    $("#busy-indicator").fadeIn();
    return false;
  });
});
```